# Wordpress make font-size responsive inside boxes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme right now and I am wondering how to adapt font size of text inside boxes so that it always stays in the middle.

In my page at some point I have 3 rows in a section, with 3 images and in the first row I also have a text saying "En savoir plus" that is inside the image :

[my wordpress section & rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCyNq.png)

The section and its rows are responsive.

[What it looks like without reducing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIUsL.png)

I have a class for that row that is set to "image" and the text is inside

so I have put this code inside a HTML row:

```
.image p {
position: absolute; 
top: 86%;
width:100%;
color:white;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.image {
position: relative; 
}
```

As you can see the text-align center works perfectly when the page is normal.

But when you reduce it, my page looks like this :

[After reducing a little the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScuWC.png)

And when you reduce it again, my page looks like this :

[After reducing a lot my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs0So.png)

What I would like is the text to change size and stay at the same place (center of the blue thing) proportionally when the boxe changes size. I will then duplicate this to all boxes.

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help guys, I would really appreciate is as I am kind of new to this :)

PS : I don't know if it helps but I am using the POFO template.

Have a wonderful day!

EDIT : All the code of my page :

```
  <style>
.bordure {
   border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}

.sub-menu > li > a {
   color: blue !important;
}

nav.navbar.bootsnav .simple-dropdown .dropdown-menu > li {
background-color: white !important;
}

.simple-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
background: white !important;
}

a {
color:#71c9dd;
}

header.sticky nav.navbar-default, header.sticky nav.navbar.bootsnav { 
background-color: transparent !important;
}

.pofo-footer-bottom {
display:none;
}

.texte_cabot {
z-index: 700;
position: absolute;
top: 550px;
left: 1600px;
font-size: 40pt;
}

header nav.navbar-default, nav.navbar.bootsnav, .full-width-pull-menu {
background-image: url('http://newstart.visceral.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/bg_header.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent !important;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

header nav .nav-header-container {
padding-bottom: 163px !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.box-layout {
    margin-top:-55px;
}

a:hover {
color:black;
}

body {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

.image p {
position: absolute; 
top: 86%;
width:100%;
color:white;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.image {
position: relative; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 778)
header nav.navbar-default, nav.navbar.bootsnav, .full-width-pull-menu  {
background: url('http://newstart.visceral.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/small_bg_header.png') repeat-x !important;
background-size: cover !important;
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

</style>
```

EDIT : Entire page HTML : (including POFO stylesheet (very long, sorry)) :

Tried to import it but it is too long to publish. Numbers of characters execeed. Could you please check it clicking the View code source on? : 
http://newstart.visceral.fr/fluimucil/

Comment: many people would have an idea to do this, but can help if you share a minimal example as a code snippet in your question

Comment: Tell me what more do you need and I post it ;)

Comment: post enough code so that we can all see the issues at play from right here inside SO, would then resolve it for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Okay this is all the code I have personnally added to the POFO design, do you want the stylesheet of the POFO design too ?

Comment: Can you provide the html code please?

Comment: A side observation: you shouldn't use `important!` except as a last resort. Figure out how to make your selectors apply without overriding the specificity rules. This can make your code a nightmare for anyone else attempting to alter it, not to mention for you yourself a year or so from now.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your time. I uploaded the link of the website, could you please check the source code by clicking the View code command ? I could not upload the entire source code since it is too long.

Comment: Thank you BobRodes for your comment, that is true. But if I do not mention !important, I have to modify all the rules of the basic CSS style which is not really handy. I know this is not easy to ready but there is only some important! and my problem cannot come from there… :/